# Polynomial coefficients from GF(2^k) to GF(2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, galois-extensions

I'm working with polynomials over $GF(2^k)^n$, so with polynomials with coefficients over $GF(2^k)$, the base field. Is there a way to transform these polynomials so that I can work (e.g., multiply them) with polynomials with coefficients over $GF(2)$?

Thank you!

Comment: Maaaaaaybe? Why do you want to?

Comment: Just curiosity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $GF(2^k)\cong\mathbb Z_p[y]/(f(y))$ where $f(y)$ is an irreducible polynomial mod $p$ and of degree $k$, you could say that $F_{p^k}[x]\cong \mathbb Z_p[x,y]/(f(y))$.

So you could compute all your products in $\mathbb Z_2[x,y]$ and then reduce mod $f(y)$.

Comment: I was just writing this out. womp womp :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you show me an example or have you got any bibliography which makes some examples about products in $\mathbb{Z}_2 [x,y]$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was thinking in a wrong way, when I posted the comment. I solved, thank you again! :)